# Position: Sticky flickers during Scroll in Microsoft Edge, but not in other browsers

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass, microsoft-edge

I have a Navigation bar that reaches across my pages and follows the viewport when scrolling by using `position:sticky`  The only class (I beleive) this really worth posting is `.secondary-heading` but i did not want to rule out the possibility of other scss affecting my issue.

```
.secondary-heading {
  // This is the class in question....
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  // The remainder might not be necessary... 
  .tab-bar {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: $white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 25px;
    &:not(.with-title) {
      box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px $medium-gray;
    }
    img {
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    >div {
      a {
        @include font-size(20);
        padding: 0 15px;
        color: $dark-gray;
        position: relative;
        top: -4px;
        padding-bottom: 19px;
        padding-top: 25px;
        &:hover {
          color: $sea-blue;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        &.active {
          background-color: $standard-gray;              
          color: white;
          &:hover {
            color: white;
            cursor: initial;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .title-bar {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: $standard-gray;        
    color: white;
    @include font-size(30);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px $medium-gray;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    span {
      margin-left: 240px;
    }
  }
}
```

On Chrome and Firefox, this styling works perfectly and scrolls as expected with the page, but in Edge, the bar flickers as it scrolls.  Is there a way to style this so the bar does not flicker?

Here is my HTML for the NavBar:

```
<div class="secondary-heading">
  <div class="tab-bar" [class.with-title]="showTitleBar">
    <div>
      <a routerLink="#" i18n>Home</a>
      <a routerLink="#" i18n>Link</a>
      <a routerLink="#" i18n>Link</a>
    </div>        
  </div>
  <div class="title-bar">
    <span>{{ headerTitle }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the versioning:

`Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0` `Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134`

Comment: It appears as though I will be just be forced to use `position:fixed` and set the `top` value dynamically..

Comment: Can you post a video or a picture of output on your side? Also try to post full code, Because with the present code i am not able to produce the issue in Edge. It can help us to find the exact issue in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to use `position: fixed` while in IE as well as Edge.  Not ideal, but I was able to get the result that I was looking for.  Just still waiting on Microsoft to catch up...

Comment: This is a browser bug, though it appears the Microsoft team has closed it as "Not reproducible". I still see the issue as of Edge v18, though. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17555420/

Comment: I too still see it as a bug in our product..also with Edge v18